# How to format Date in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to write a small Google Script which takes data from some cells of Google Sheet and Paste it in the GMAIL.
However, while pasting the 'Date Values' it always displays it in the following manner:-

- Mon Apr 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
- Fri Apr 26 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

But I need the dates in an appropriate way i.e.

- "Mon Apr 15 2019"  or
- "Fri 04/26/2019"

I gone through these possible options i.e. `Utilities.formatDate` & `.Split` but somehow I am not able to write these codes appropriately. Can you please help me with this matter. Below I have mentioned the entire issue in detail.

My Code

```
function temp2() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var emailTemplate2 = templateSheet.getRange("G1").getValue();
  var rec = templateSheet.getRange("C1").getValue();
  var sub = templateSheet.getRange("D1").getValue();
  var date = templateSheet.getRange("E1").getValue();
//  Logger.log(rec);
  MailApp.sendEmail(rec, sub, emailTemplate2);
```

}

here `var date = templateSheet.getRange("E1").getValue();` is the part of code which picks value of date.

Do let me know if you need more details in this regard
Regards,
Alok

Answer (score 2):

#### Requirement:

Format date value from cell in Google Apps Script.

---

#### Solution:

Pass value to date constructor `new Date()` then format using `Utilities.formatDate()`.

```
// pass date to date constructor
var date = new Date(templateSheet.getRange("E1").getValue());

// "Mon Apr 15 2019" example
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+0", 'E MMM dd yyyy');

// "Fri 04/26/2019" example
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date, "GMT+0", 'E MM/dd/yyyy');
```

**Note**: I've set this to timezone "GMT+0" by default, you can change this to whichever time zone you need.

---

#### References:

1. [`new Date()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) for date constructor.
2. [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) for formatting dates in Google Apps Script.
3. [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for date format strings.

Comment: `getValue()` returns date object. You don't need a constructor.

Comment: Hi, if I use the following script, it gives an error of "Cannot find method formatDate(string,string,string)."

`Utilities.formatDate(templateSheet.getRange("E3").getValue(),"GMT+0", 'E MMM dd yyyy')`

Comment: @TheMaster Pretty sure you still need the constructor, see error above...

Comment: @AlokNagar try passing the date to the `new Date()` constructor before you format it, like in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help @ross, can we use any chop option to get the desired value in Google Script. E.g. from "Mon Apr 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)" if I can extract first 15 texts i.e. "Mon Apr 15 2019" ?
I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: Yes it's possible with simple string manipulation, however then you'll have a string not a date object.

Comment: @AlokNagar the code provided in the question will give you the result you're expecting, it returns the date object in format "Mon Apr 15 2019"...

Comment: @ross Although OP's error does suggest that it's a string, It's possible that it was never a date type in the spreadsheet.. `Logger.log(typeof templateSheet.getRange("E1").getValue())`  logged `object` for a date in E1, `number` and `string` for number and a string in E1 respectively. And `Utilities.formatDate()` did work for me without a constructor. It's also possible that I'm overlooking something else, but dates in spreadsheet are returned as date objects in `getValue`(s)`()`, AFAICT.

Comment: @TheMaster Yeah, it's pretty hard to tell if it's a date object or not since we don't have a copy of OP's sheet available. I tested and also did not need to pass it to the date constructor but I guess to save any confusion it's easier to include it in the answer, rather than leaving it out and causing potential errors because the user's dates are not formatted as such.

Comment: @Alok Is it E1 or E3? Your code `Utilities.formatDate(templateSheet.getRange("E3").getValue(),"GMT+0", 'E MMM dd yyyy')` used E3.

Comment: @ross I would agree with you. But, if they are datestrings, the constructor may or may not change it to a date. [parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). I think the best way is to fix it in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @TheMaster interesting, I had not read this article. Thanks for this I'll keep it in mind for the future.